# Navigation Drawer open at application start-up

Tags: android, material-design, navigation-drawer

I'm sure I read that Navigation Drawer should be open when the application opens for the first time. Probably here: https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation-drawer.html But I cannot find it any more. **Is this behavior still recommended?**

Comment: well... i haven't seen anyone create an app with navigation drawer opened up at application startup.

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaking the Navigation drawer behaviour with the introduction behaviour.

**First Look:**

The first time someone open your application, they should be introduced to the app by showing them where to go and what is important. One of these show cases is showing the navigation drawer when your app starts for the first time.

**Any time after that:**

Your app should not show the navigation drawer when the app starts. For the main reason that they know it is there, and it would be redundant if they see it again and again at the start of your app every time.

Comment: My question is clear. Any links to documentation/official guidelines that drawer should be open first time?